# Specifying signal delays in SystemC as clause AFTER in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, systemc

I have a problem in SystemC trying to write a signal after some time passes...

Consider the following:

```
process (clk)
   begin
      -- Updating my signal, out signal, in order to get result, but after a certain delay.
      signal1 <= '0' after 2 ns;
```

OK!
I can do the same in SystemC:

```
SC_CTOR(MyModule) {
   SC_METHOD(mymethod);
   sensitive << ....
}
void mymethod() {
   mysig = '0'; // HOW TO SAY AFTER 2 NS?????????
}
```

How can I specify a delay for signal assignment in SystemC????

Answer (score 2):

I think you can `wait(2, SC_NS);` in `SC_THREAD`s, but not in a `SC_METHOD`s. (AFAIK, you're not allowed to `wait` in `SC_METHOD`s.)

Comment: no you can't use `wait` in `SC_METHOD`. `wait()` function calls yeild on current fiber, and there is no where to switch to, so it would cause a crash.

Comment: I had the same question and was unable to find what Gene is talking about. The way I ended up doing it was a separate wait() statement followed by the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm forgetting SC syntax already, but it should be similar to GBL, the `write` function should take an optional delay parameter, like `mysig.write(0, 2*SC_NS);` In GBL it's either `mysig.Write(0, 2*ns);` or alternative syntax: `mysig(2*ns) = 0;`